# How do I make names that start with the letter K appear only in the console

Tags: javascript

i need to **make names that start with the letter K appear only in the console**

```
let friends = ["keven", "Khaled", "keiven", 1, 2, "coder", "zein"];
let i = 0;
let counter = 0;


while (i < friends.length) {
    console.log(friends[i])
    i++
    if (friends[i][counter] === friends[i].includes("A")) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: for a simple one liner you could try `let filteredFriends = friends.filter(friend => String(friend).toLowerCase().startsWith('k'))`

Answer (score 0):

1. loop over the array
2. get the first letter as lowerCase
3. check if it equals to 'k'

```
    const friends = ["keven", "Khaled", "keiven", 1, 2, "coder", "zein"];
    for(let friend of friends){
        if(String(friend[0]).toLowerCase() === 'k'){
            console.log(friend);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what does it mean friends of friends?

Comment: The `for...of` statement creates a loop iterating over iterable objects.
with syntax:
`for (variable of iterable) {  statement}`
for more information check: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

 @Zein-Waleed1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `forEach` syntax to cycle over your array, and then printing only the elements matching your request (so elements that are string **and** starts with a "k" letter).

```js
friends.forEach((elem) => {
  if(elem.toString().toLowerCase().startsWith("k"))
    console.log(elem)
})
```

Comment: bro i tried your code but its not working

Comment: What does it mean "it's not working"?